# keyboardWillChangeFrame not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I expected the keyboardWillChangeFrame to be called for every point when dragging the keyboard up or down. I am using keyboardDismissMode = .interactive.

Instead, keyboardWillChangeFrame is only called when the keyboard is only fully opened or closed.

Is there a different way to get the effect I want?

Comment: By Dragging you meant the keyboard coming from bottom to the final frame? Also it will be helpful if you can tell the purpose of why you need the keyboard frame as it does the animation?.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to add interactive panning using this repo:
[https://github.com/totocaster/Typist](https://github.com/totocaster/Typist#interactivity-and-inputaccessoryview)

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code to get exact frame of keyboard everytime it did end change so if you will change keyboard to english or emoji it will give right frame every time..

```
   func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.size.height
                print("keyboard height: \(keyboardHeight)")
                self.bottomConstrainttypeTextView.constant = -keyboardHeight
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }
        }
```

this how you can use it just add observer for notification for keyboard change trigger

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

Comment: This is only called for me at the end of the animation. not during the animation.

Comment: yes it will be called when keyboard totally appears on screen